# A line can be interpreted as both a vector space and a function. Can a plane too?

Tags: linear-algebra, functions

A line can be interpreted as both a vector space and a function.
For example,

$$(x,y,z) = (x_0,y_0,z_0) + t(a,b,c).$$
This can be seen as a function
$$D1 : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^3}$$
or $$D1 : \mathbb{R^3} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^3}.$$
Also,
$$(x,y,z) = (x_0,y_0,z_0) + t(a,b,c) \iff \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R^3} \mid x = x_0 + ta,y = y_0 + tb, z = z_0 + tc, t\in \mathbb{R}\}.$$

So is this why we say the image of a linear transformation is a vector space?

Also, can a plane be a function too? For instance, some ways to show a plane in $\mathbb{R^3}$ are

$$ax+by+cz+d=0 \iff \vec{n} \cdot(\vec{r}-\vec{r_0}) = 0 \iff \{(x,y,z) \mid ax+by+zc+d=0\}.$$

Can we also see a plane as a function? I can't see it directly from the formulas above.

Comment: do people really say this? "*we say a linear transformation is also a vector space*". I might say "a set of linear transformations can be a vector space" (if the set satisfies the appropriate axioms). Or maybe you mean in the sense "*the image of* a linear transformation is also a vector space"

Comment: Perhaps it's helpful to be more precise and note that, for example, f(x) = 2x is a function, and its *graph* is a vector space.

Comment: ok I see, i'll edit my question

Comment: the "is a function"  makes no sense. There is a parametrization for your $n \cdot (r-r_0)=0$  by finding two linearly independent vectors $u,v,$  that are perpendicular to $n,$  then   $\vec r = \vec r_0 + s \vec u + t \vec v$

Answer (score 1):

In much more generality than you ask about, the range of any function is a subset of its codomain. If the function is injective then the range "looks like" a copy of the domain. I think that's what you mean when you say that the range can be interpreted as "both a subspace (a set) and a function".

In your context, you are asking about an affine subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (or any finite dimensional vector space): those are translates $v+S$ of some $d$ dimensional subspace $S$ of $V$. By choosing a basis of $S$ you can write $S$ as (isomorphic to) $\mathbb{R}^d$. Then $A$ looks like a copy of $\mathbb{R}^d$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$. For planes $S$ in space (and in general for subspaces of dimension $n-1$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$) you can also describe $S$ as the set of vectors perpendicular to some vector.